# django sort on calculated model field -- can I use .extra?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the model below.  I want to order by percent_vote.  I know I could calculate the value and save to a new field in the model, but I prefer not to go that way.  Is there some way to use .extra method to do this?

Django 1.6, sqlite3

```
class HallOfFame(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Master)
    year = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    voted_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ballots_cast = models.IntegerField()
    votes_needed = models.IntegerField()
    votes_received = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    inducted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    needed_note = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.player.name_first, self.player.name_last) 

    def percent_vote(self):
        try:
            return self.votes_received/float(self.ballots_cast)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue with the code below.  @Emil Davtyan's answer didn't work for me, and I wanted to figure out a more general solution.

```
def home(request):
    hall =  HallOfFame.objects.filter(inducted=True, voted_by='BBWAA')  
    hall_sorted = sorted(hall, key=lambda member: member.percent_vote, reverse=True)[:20]
    return render_to_response('top_lists.html', {'hall': hall_sorted })
```

the model has this:

```
   @property
    def percent_vote(self):
        try:
            return float(self.votes_received)/self.ballots_cast

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems you can do something like this, but this may depend on the your database backend ( this should work for PostgreSQL ):

```
q = HallOfFame.objects.extra(select={'percent_vote_integer': "votes_received/ballots_cast", 'percent_vote_remainder': "votes_received%ballots_cast"})
q = q.extra(order_by = ['percent_vote_integer', percent_vote_remainder])
```

Comment: Thanks for your example.  I'm using sqlite3 and it didn't seem to work properly.  What I would really like to do is be able to use a method that calculates the value because I have other situations where the calculation isn't so simple.